# Right margin discrepancy between framed and fbox/minipage

Tags: margins, framed

Here is an MWE which shows that something is weird in the `framed` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength{\FrameSep}{3pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
  \noindent\lipsum[2]
\end{framed}

\noindent\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: right margin discrepancy]

Why does the `framed` environment disagree with minipage about where the right margin should be? Is there an easy way to get the two to line up?

(The `framed` package claims to be a "preproduction version" and its documentation is dated 2007. Could we have new maintainers maybe?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`framed` does it well. The way you use `\fbox`, framing over the complete linewidth, exceeds the text width. The `minipage` has correct width, but `\fbox` adds to it. This should cause a warning.

As written in the comment below, calculating the width of the `minipage` would solve it:

```
\noindent\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}%
    \textbackslash fbox: \lipsum[1]
  \end{minipage}%
}
```

For illustration, here's a screenshot without that correction, comparing normal text, framed and fboxed text:

[image: frames example]

Comment: So would `\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth - 3pt}...` work?

Comment: @Seamus: It works similarly. I would calculate it: `\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep`.