# framebox and margins

Tags: margins, framed

I have 2 minipages, the second of which is `\frameboxed`.

The `\framebox` command seems to push the minipage out into the right margin, as you can see.

[image: Imgur]

[This is not the same as a previous question:  [Right margin discrepancy between framed and fbox/minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12670).  Whilst it may have a related answer, it is not the same question.  I am not interested in the `\fbox` command or the `framed` package.]

How do I prevent `\framebox` from transgressing the right margin in this way?  It is playing havoc with my RTL documents!

The MWE is here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\end{minipage}%

\bigskip

\framebox{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can do `\framebox{\noindent\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
...
\end{minipage}}`

Comment: This comes close, but the box still sticks out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this make sense?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\end{minipage}%

\bigskip

\noindent
\framebox{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the box doesn't stick out into the right margin. I added the `showframe` package to better show the edges. It should be noted that this method is very similar to the one proposed in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12670/right-margin-discrepancy-between-framed-and-fbox-minipage?rq=1).

Comment: Mine sticks out: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/TV4Pop7.png?1).  Any ideas?  But I'll use the answer, and the link is useful.  Can we keep the question please  for other newbies like me who don't realise that fbox is like framebox.  I see your point

Answer (score 3):

The solution propose by @AboAmmar works fine, but I suggest using the `framed` environment, which allows for page breaking inside frames, which `minipage` does not allow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{12cm}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word
\end{minipage}%

\bigskip

\noindent\framebox{\noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax}
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word
  \end{minipage}%
}

\bigskip
\setlength\FrameSep{\fboxsep}
\begin{framed}\noindent
  word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word
  word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word

  \lipsum[1]
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: unfortunately framed, whilst it solves this problem, introduces other problems.  So I prefer the other solution.

Comment: @Tim: Simple curiosity: What kind of problems? I don't use framed very often, but I never had any trouble.